# Regex matching not working in jquery-highlighttextarea library

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using [`jquery-highlighttextarea`](https://github.com/mistic100/jquery-highlighttextarea) library and `jquery-1.7.2.js` for a sample application which is targeting to match and highlight a `valid IPv4 address` in an `input` tag.

There is a facility to match and highlight a text based on a `regex`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {         
    $( "#demo1" ).keypress(function() {
        $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
          words: {
            color: '#ADF0FF',
            words: ['[0-9]{1,3}'] // regex goes here
          }
        });
    });
  });
```

HTML :

```
<body> 
  <article> 
   <input id="demo1" class="inputBox"></input>
  </article>
</body>
```

I used `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` as the regex to catch the IP address.[It was in here.](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {         
    $( "#demo1" ).keypress(function() {
        $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
          words: {
            color: '#ADF0FF',
            words: ['(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)']
          }
        });
    });
  });  
</script>
```

But the problem is now it's not matching the text correctly. i.e. it will take this (`256.2.3`) and this (`23 123.123.123`) as valid IPs.

I think someone familiar with regex or this particular library can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `words` value is a string that requires double slashes to escape regex metacharacters. Right now, the `\.` inside it is treated as a special regex subpattern matching any character but a newline, that is why you get matches where you do not want to.

It is always safer to use character classes to "wrap" such characters so as they are treated as literal symbols.

Use

```
words: ['(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)']
```

If you need to validate the string that is exactly the IPv4 address (i.e. it should only contain the IPv4 address), you will be safer using `^` (=string start) and `$` (=string end) anchors:

```
words: ['^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$']
```

Comment: btw if you can please share a way to select all the other things expect IP addresses.  Basically if I need to negate the whole regex to select all other that what it meant by the regex how can I do that ?

Comment: This is much harder to do without `!regex.test(str)`.